# Only prints the last server in the list, I want all servers

Tags: powershell, citrix

This only prints the last server in the list, I'm looking to get all servers and print to screen

```
$machines = (Get-BrokerMachine -AdminAddress $adminaddress -DesktopGroupName $deliverygroup | Select-Object DNSname).DNSname

foreach($machine in $machines){

$machinelist = Get-BrokerMachine -HostedMachineName $machine
    if($machinelist.InMaintenanceMode -eq $true){
        $status = "$machine is in maintenance mode"
        }else  {
        $status = "$machine is not in maintenance mode"
        }

}
Write-Host $status
```

Answer (score 2):

`$Status` is constantly being overwritten by the current machine in your list.

You're looking for:

```
$Status+=
```

As opposed to:

```
$Status=
```

---

You'll also want to explicitly state that `$Status` will be an array at the beginning like so:

```
$Status=@()
```

Or when you create the variable and omit the line at the beginning.

```
[array]$Status +=
```

Otherwise, you'll get results that run together as it will be treated as a `[String]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more PowerShell-like approach (not tested):

```
Get-BrokerMachine -AdminAddress $adminaddress -DesktopGroupName $deliverygroup | ForEach-Object {
  $machineName = $_.DNSName
  [PSCustomObject] @{
    "MachineName"     = $machineName
    "MaintenanceMode" = (Get-BrokerMachine -HostedMachineName $machine).InMaintenanceMode
  }
} | Export-Csv "C:\whatever\results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The only problem with this one is that I need to store it in a variable so that I can email that list

Comment: You didn't say that in your question. You said you wanted to see them on the screen. Updated my answer to export to a CSV file (requires PowerShell 3.0 or newer).

Answer (score 0):

another funky mode :

```
function get-BrokerMachineMode
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string[]]$machines
    )
    begin
    {
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
        Add-Type -Language CSharp @"
public class BrokenBroker {
        qpublic System.String MachineName;
        public System.String MaintenanceMode;

public  BrokenBroker (string MachineName, string MaintenanceMode)
    {
        this.MachineName  = MachineName;
        this.MaintenanceMode = IsInMaintenanceMode;
    }
}
"@

        $status = @()
        Write-Verbose "Created objects..."
    }
    process
    {
        try
        {
            $machines = (Get-BrokerMachine -AdminAddress $adminaddress `
                                           -DesktopGroupName $deliverygroup | Select-Object DNSname).DNSname

            foreach ($machine in $machines)
            {
                Write-Verbose "Checking machine: $machine"

                $machinelist = Get-BrokerMachine -HostedMachineName $machine

                if ($machinelist.InMaintenanceMode -eq $true)
                {
                    $status += New-Object BrokenBroker($machine, $true)
                }
                else
                {
                    $status += New-Object BrokenBroker($machine, $false)
                }

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Error $error[0].Exception.Message
        }
        $status
    }
    end
    {
        Write-Verbose "Done"
    }

}
```

this is a function you just must to load then you can launch it just by using this command:

```
$computers = get-content = {PATH TO TXT FILE}
$list = get-BrokerMachineMode -machines $computers -Verbose
```